# Choice of Occupation and Negative Childhood Experiences

Tags: io-psychology

Is there any evidence to suggest that individuals that were bullied in school as children select occupations that are a means of making people obligated to respect them? For example people that join the police?

My premise is based on observations of a majority of individuals in law enforcement having personality traits that are consistent with the descriptions of the [Authoritarian Personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authoritarian_personality), and I felt that childhood experiences of being unable to cope or predict norms of their social environment may be a good explanation as to why they choose a career that enforces a consistency in the accepted social norms of the society.

Comment: That isn't different very different to other SE sites at all.